# converting kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA sampleBuffer to kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, cmsamplebuffer, janus-gateway

i am using janus gateway for my webrtc app and capturing samplebuffer from my camera as kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA because i am doing face with the samplebuffer and can't use directly kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange to send it directly to janus.
So my question is , how can i convert RGBA pixel format of samplebuffer to 420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange samplebuffer

i didn't find any script that do this form of conversion , i know there is a code to convert 420Y to RGBA and not opposite.

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

//WebRTC delegate
externalVideoBufferDelegate?.captureOutput!(output, didOutput: sampleBuffer, from: connection)

 if i % 40 == 0 {
  let visionImage = VisionImage(buffer: sampleBuffer)
  let metadata = VisionImageMetadata()
  metadata.orientation = .rightTop
  visionImage.metadata = metadata
  faceDetector.process(visionImage) { features, error in
  for feature in faces {

  print("detected")
  }
   if faces.isEmpty  {

   print("Scan Failed: Found nothing to scan :")
  }
  }

}
}
```

i expect an Y420 samplebuffer from the default 32RGBA samplebuffer

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the video output settings for your capture sessions:

```
let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: outputQueue)
videoOutput.videoSettings = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange)
        ]
```